# Is there any way to get the latest changes that i have done while resolving merge conflicts in GIT?

Tags: git, github

I raised a Gerrit which was not merged then next day, I took a git pull, got merge conflicts, was resolving merge conflicts but also added a few changes which were not related to conflicts and also forgot to take a patch of changed files then I added all the files using git add. Is there any way to get the changes that I have done or all the changes that I have done while resolving merge conflicts? I have not pushed code to remote yet.

I am new to GIT. Please help me out.

Comment: I think what you want is to see the changes in the merge commit.  In an ideal world where there is no conflict, there are no changes that need to be recorded.  But when you do, the changes you introduced to resolve the conflict are recorded in the merge commit.  A simple `git show MERGE-COMMIT-ID` will show them to you.  Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

To see differences between your version and the most recent version, try git diff.

Additionally,
If you need to get the most recent revisions to a remote repository, you can use git fetch.

To compare between a fetch and your version, try git diff HEAD HEAD^

You can reference this article for advanced git actions. i find it really helpful
https://dev.to/maxpou/git-cheat-sheet-advanced-3a17

Answer (score 0):

Set a branch here.... say `temp`. `git branch temp`.

Now, do you want to retry the merge? The go back to where things were before merging and merge again. When you are done with the merge (say, you are on branch blah):

```
git checkout --detach temp
git reset --soft blah
# all things you did on top of the merge are now in index
git commit -m "things not from the merge"
# now, set the branch that you like here
git branch -f blah
```